# Protractor splitting data driven tests into different specs

Tags: protractor

My test reads data rows from excel. Each row is an individual test case.

```
specs: ['SetOne.js', 'SetTwo.js'],

capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 3,
},
```

Right now I literally had to make two spec files - SetOne.js and SetTwo.js. Both the files are identical. Only difference is SetOne.js runs rows 0-5 and SetTwo.js runs rows 6-10.

Is this the right approach? What if there are 100 rows and I want to run 10 test cases on each instance. In that case create 10 identical specs and specify which rows each spec runs?

Answer (score 0):

Use `excel` is awful approach. You could take a look at data provider's idea. For example this [first implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider) what I found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fast-csv to parse the input CSV https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv

[image]

Create a JSON array with two diff property eg(SUM,SUB). Creates dynamically based on D column

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");
var jsonStr = '{}'
var obj1 = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
csv
.fromPath("input1.csv", { comment: '#', quote: null, discardUnmappedColumns: true, delimiter: ';', ignoreEmpty: true, trim: true})
.on("data", function (data) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(`${data[3]}`)) {
        //add the row data to the property eg: SUB and SUB
        obj1[`${data[3]}`].push(data);
    }
    else {
        //Create a new property based on data[3] (i.e) SUB and SUM
        //Creates a property if not exist eg: SUB and SUB
        obj1[`${data[3]}`] = [];
        obj1[`${data[3]}`].push(data);
    }
})
```

Use this JSON object to in stepdefinition

```
Object.keys(obj1).forEach((value) => {

var a = `obj1.${value}`;

describe(`${value}`, function () {

        it('Should .............', function () {
           // test
           if(value.OPR === "SUM"){
           return expect(sum(value.INT_1,sum.INT_2)).to.eventually.equal(value.EXP);
           }
           if(value.OPR === "SUB"){
           return expect(sub(value.INT_1,sum.INT_2)).to.eventually.equal(value.EXP);
           }
           else{
           return this.skipped();
           }

        })
    })

})
```